# How to add grand total to this query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

With this query:

```
With EX1 AS
(
SELECT
idcompany,
idemploy,
import
FROM data
WHERE
idcompany in ('000405', '000102')
)
SELECT * 
FROM EX1
UNION ALL
SELECT idcompany, 'Total', sum(import) from EX1
GROUP BY idcompany
ORDER BY
idcompany,
idemploy
```

I get:

```
idcompany idemploy import
000102    0000001     100
000102    0000002     200
000102     Total      300
000405    0000001      50
000405    0000002      70
000405     Total      120
```

And I'd like to get:

```
idcompany idemploy import
000102    0000001     100
000102    0000002     200
000102     Total      300
000405    0000001      50
000405    0000002      70
000405     Total      120
Grand      Total      420
```

What code do I have to add to the query, and *where* should I add it? Thanks.

Comment: if your question is answered, please mark it answered.

Answer (score 2):

You can append a

```
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Grand', 'Total', sum(import) from EX1
```

to your query.

Comment: Where do I need to append this line of code in the query?

Comment: @LuciaDeetz: the same way you did with the `UNION ALL` in your question

Comment: Append "b" to a String "a" would result in "ab".

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `ROLLUP` sub-clause of the `GROUP BY` clause (Postgres 9.5+) along with the `Grouping` function which is ideally suited for such operations and is efficient than those `UNION ALL`s

[Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS)

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN GROUPING(idcompany) = 1
            AND GROUPING(idemploy) = 1
            THEN 'Grand'
        ELSE idcompany
        END AS idcompany
    ,CASE GROUPING(idemploy)
        WHEN 1
            THEN 'Total'
        ELSE idemploy
        END AS idemploy
    ,SUM(import)
FROM data
GROUP BY ROLLUP(idcompany, idemploy);
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=df96bff5e1474bbf7415ce08a197d743)

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately we're using Postgresql 9.4.